# tso package in R

Tags: r, outliers

I am detecting different outliers from a series, and every time I run second variable from second column in a series I get this error below:

```r
Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 6.87331e-17
```

Here is my R code:

```r
outliers_excess_ts <- tso(myts, types = c("TC", "AO", "LS", "IO", "SLS"),maxit.iloop=12)
outliers_excess_ts
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you mean [`tsooutliers`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsoutliers/)? I can find no reference to a `tso` *package*. (I suspect it'll be hard to answer this question without being reproducible.)

Comment: oh ya I mean tsooutliers, so the actual problem is this error :`Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 6.87331e-17.` I think it has to do with the matrix.